# Determine if Thin server is running as daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have problem with Rails and Thin server. For some reason, Thin clears out the ARGV variable (I don't even ask why :/), and my Rails application needs to determine if Thin is running as daemon server. I tried to access/find server object in application and rack variables, but with no luck. If any way to access Thin instance options, or even original ARGV, so i can parse it and figure out if Thin is running as daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Solved :)

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Thin::Runner) { |obj| @options = obj.options }
@options[:daemonize]
```